# How do I tell if Intent extras exist in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have this code that checks for a value of an extra in an Intent on an Activity that is called from many places in my app:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isNewItem")
```

If isNewItem isn't set, will my code crash? Is there any way to tell if it's been set or not before I call it?

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

As others have said, both `getIntent()` and `getExtras()` may return null. Because of this, you don't want to chain the calls together, otherwise you might end up calling `null.getBoolean("isNewItem");` which will throw a `NullPointerException` and cause your application to crash.

Here's how I would accomplish this. I think it's formatted in the nicest way and is very easily understood by someone else who might be reading your code.

```
// You can be pretty confident that the intent will not be null here.
Intent intent = getIntent();

// Get the extras (if there are any)
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("isNewItem")) {
        boolean isNew = extras.getBoolean("isNewItem", false);

        // TODO: Do something with the value of isNew.
    }
}
```

You don't actually need the call to `containsKey("isNewItem")` as `getBoolean("isNewItem", false)` will return false if the extra does not exist. You could condense the above to something like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    boolean isNew = extras.getBoolean("isNewItem", false);
    if (isNew) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

You can also use the `Intent` methods to access your extras directly. This is probably the cleanest way to do so:

```
boolean isNew = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isNewItem", false);
```

Really any of the methods here are acceptable. Pick one that makes sense to you and do it that way.

Comment: I have a problem understanding why people use `getExtras()` in the first place. Why do it? The `Intent` class has all of the methods needed to get any type of `extra` - there's no need to get the `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks @Squonk, that's a good point. Sometimes it's a little cleaner to fetch the whole `Bundle` from the `Intent` when you have a lot of extras to enumerate.

Comment: Thinking about it, my comment was mostly based on the fact that I usually want to analyse the `Intent`. For instance, I want to know the 'action', 'category' and so on. To do this I'll get the `Intent` first then concentrate on the extras later. In the case of the OP's question your answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal because is 'intent.hasExtras' http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You should note that if there are more than one extra you should use the variable `Intent intent = getIntent()` to avoid making more than one call to the `getIntent()` method

Comment: Just to add: snooping at Android SourceCode, `extras.getBoolean(KEY)` implies `extras.getBoolean(KEY, false)`.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("isNewItem")) {
   intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isNewItem");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not the `getBoolean()` but the `getIntent().getExtras()`

Test this way:

```
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null)
  myBoolean = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isNewItem");
```

by the way, if `isNewItem` doesn't exist, it returns de default vaule `false`.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent()` will return `null` if there is no `Intent` so use...

```
boolean isNewItem = false;
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i != null)
    isNewItem = i.getBooleanExtra("isNewItem", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not crash unless until you use it! You don't have to get it if it exists but if you try, for some reason, to use a an "extra" which doesn' exists your system will crash.

So, try o do something like:

```
final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

boolean myBool=false;

if(bundle != null) {
    myBool = bundle.getBoolean("isNewItem");
}
```

This way you make sure your app won't crash. (and make sure you have a valid `Intent` :))